# Should I aim to have child documents stored in separate collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, normalization, nosql

I've constructed some mongoose schemas with a not too complicated parent child structure. When I create my parents I include an array of jsons which match the child schema and the child documents get created ok but don't appear in a separate child collection in mongodb.

However, if I later append some more children then these do appear in the separate child collection in mongodb with a duplicate/reference in the parent (I create them using Model.create as I need to get access to their ObjectId)

As I'm new to NoSQL I'm not sure if I should still be trying to keep a separate collection of the child documents. Are there any negative impacts to having only some of my children appearing in the separate collection?

### Minimal sample code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    arrangementSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        abc: String
    }),
    tuneSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        arrangements: [arrangementSchema]
    });

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/jnr_dev');


var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {

});

var Arrangement = mongoose.model('Arr', arrangementSchema),
    Tune = mongoose.model('Tu', tuneSchema);


var tune = Tune.create({
    name: 'test'
}, function (err, newTune) {
    newTune.arrangements = [{abc:'abc1'}];
    newTune.save(function () {
        Arrangement.create({
            abc: 'abc2'
        }, function (err, arr) {
            newTune.arrangements.push(arr);
            newTune.save();
        });
    })
});

// and same behaviour with

var tune = Tune.create({
    name: 'test',
    arrangements: [{abc:'abc3'}]
}, function (err, newTune) {
    Arrangement.create({
        abc: 'abc4'
    }, function (err, arr) {
        newTune.arrangements.push(arr);
        newTune.save();
    });
});
```

### Result in Tus collection

```
 {    "__v": NumberInt(2),    "_id": ObjectId("511037ef60e5af0000000002"),    "arrangements": {
     "0": {
       "abc": "abc1",
       "_id": ObjectId("511037ef60e5af0000000003")
    },
     "1": {
       "_id": ObjectId("511037ef60e5af0000000004"),
       "abc": "abc2"
    }   },    "name": "test" }
```

### Result in Arrs collection

```
 {
   "abc": "abc2",
   "_id": ObjectId("511037ef60e5af0000000004"),
   "__v": NumberInt(0)
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an unexpected result. Can you post some complete, runnable, minimal example code here that reproduces the problem so we can help diagnose?

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis Have attached sample. I should've mentioned in the original post I was using mongoose too

Answer (score 0):

It's the Arrangement.create() call that creates documents in the second collection. I assume you want an array of subdocuments within the Tune collection, only. See:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

You should just do:

```
newTune.arrangements.push({
    abc: 'abc4'
});

newTune.save();
```

Comment: What about when I have documents of another type `parent2` that also need to reference arrangements. Should I aim to keep a separate collection of arrangements in this case and just reference from the parents using an objectId?

Comment: In that case, yes - if you have two kinds of documents that reference a third kind, it may makes sense to keep them all separate. Please see the discussion of "embedding" and "referencing" here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-decisions

Or this:

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/schema-design-1